# Linear mixed model: kronecker product covariance matrix

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

Let's take the `Pixel` dataset as example.

```
Grouped Data: pixel ~ day | Dog/Side
    Dog Side day  pixel
1     1    R   0 1045.8
2     1    R   1 1044.5
3     1    R   2 1042.9
```

`pixel` is the response. `Dog` with 10 levels. `Side` with 2 levels. `day` with 9 levels.
I want to fit a model where the covariance matrix is the direct(kronecker) product between the 10x10 identity `Dog` matrix, 2x2 identity `Side` matrix, a the 9x9 AR1 `day` matrix.

So should it be something like

```
lme(pixel~1,corr=corAR1(form~1|Dog/Side),weights=varIdent(form=~1|Dog*Side),data=Pixel)
```

But here I have got a nesting structure between `Dog` and `Side` in the `corr` term. Although this is correct for this dataset, I want it to be cross `Dog:Side` in general. Furthermore, I am not sure the different components `corr` and `weights` will be combined together using direct product internal of `lme`.

p.s. I understand this dataset is not balanced, so not all 10x2x9=180 combinations are present. But I still need the direct product structure in general, perhaps suitably adjusted for the missing levels.